# Can GKE filter logs by application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-error-reporting

We are GKE managing several applications:

- app1
- app2
- app3

In GCP Error Reporting dashboard, errors are intermixed for all the applications.  For example, the errors below are coming from a different app.

[image]

However in the `Configure Notifications` tab, there is no option to setup alerts based on app/conditions.

I'd like to be able to setup different notifcation channels depending on app eg. `app1 -> slack, app2 -> email`.  We have different ops team that handle these apps and having them go to a shared, noisy Slack channel is not ideal.  Also, it would be great to setup alerts based on exception details - for example all Java RuntimeExceptions result in different alerts.

What the conventional way to setup fine-grained alerts like these?

Comment: do you mean you want to organise the alerts/notifications depending on the app? and as well view them accordingly? You can try [creating your own notification channel](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#create-channel) depending on what you want.

Comment: Thansk Bryan - we have separate notification channels in our GCP monitoring.  The problem we're having is that there's no fine-grained control in GCP AFAIK to send alerts based on application errors.  Like "errors thrown by java application 1 go to this channel, errors from python application 2 go to that channel"

Comment: The link that I shared to you have same instructions on how to create a [notification channel](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#configure-notifications). You can also request for a feature for this just visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)

Answer (score 0):

In the GCP Logs explorer (if in the legacy explorer, need to click upgrade) you can create an alert using this button, which will let you setup an alert anytime some criteria is met based on a log condition.

[image]

It will then create an entry in the monitoring tab under alerting and the rest is straightforward

[image]